# Remove documents from a collection based on value located in another collection

Tags: python, mongodb

I started working with mongodb yesterday. I have two collections in the same database with 100 million and 300 million documents. I want to remove documents in one collection if a value in the document is not found in any document of the second collection. To maybe make this more clear I have provided python/mongodb pseudocode code below. I realize this is not proper syntax, its just to show the logic I am after. I am looking for the most efficient way as there are a lot of records and its on my laptop :)

```
for doc_ONE in db.collection_ONE:
    if doc_ONE["arbitrary"] not in [doc_TWO["arbitrary"] for doc_TWO in db.collection_TWO]:
        db.collection_ONE.remove({"arbitrary": doc_ONE["arbitrary"]})
```

I am fine with this being done from the mongo cli if faster. Thanks for reading this and please don't flame me to hard lol.

Comment: Note: `document` appears twice in your pseudo-code, it confusing. Could you rename => `doc_one` and `doc_two`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `document["arbitrary"]` is a immuable value, you can store all the values (without duplicates) in a `set`:

values = {document["arbitrary"] for document in db.collection_TWO}

The process like you suggest:

```
for doc_one in db.collection_ONE:
    if doc_one["arbitrary"] not in values:
        db.collection_ONE.remove({"arbitrary": doc_one["arbitrary"]})
```

Comment: Do you mean values would be: values = (document["arbitrary"] for document in db.collection_TWO)? Collection_TWO does not have duplicates for "arbitrary", only collection_ONE. This is something I will only have to do once, but do to the size of the collections, I am afraid my method will take quite a while. I wasn't sure if there was some sort of secret sauce. SO, the main thing is that documents in collection_ONE should only exist if doc_ONE["arbitrary"] value exists in a doc_TWO["arbitrary"]. The collection_ONE docs are dependent on the information in collection_TWO.

Comment: Yes, `values` is a [**set**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) or [**frozsenset**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-frozenset) of existing `document["arbitrary"]` values. What kind of value is it? `int`? `str`? I'm sur Python can store a huge number of `int` or `str` in memory…

Comment: Yeah it is a great method, waaaay faster than my list method. My only concern is memory. collection_TWO has 300 million entries. It is a string value of 40 chars.

Comment: At least 11 Go! Could be on RAM : it will swap a little…

Comment: Going to give you the win. Will test it. May have to break it up somehow but I think that will be the best approach. Thanks!